# How to add class to Quarkus class loader at build time

Tags: java, quarkus, event-bus

I'm trying to build Quarkus application with external class used as a Message in EventBus.

```
@ConsumeEvent("VAVR")
Uni<Try<String>> tryUni(String message) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(Try.of(() -> {
        throw new TestException("From VAVR", 400);
    }));
}
```

and what I'm getting at build time is

```
2020-04-18 19:35:59,076 ERROR [io.qua.application] (main) Failed to start application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.vavr.control.Try<java.lang.String>
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:322)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:275)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:322)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:275)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxProcessor$build38.deploy_0(VertxProcessor$build38.zig:1123)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.VertxProcessor$build38.deploy(VertxProcessor$build38.zig:36)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:194)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:99)
at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:60)
at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:236)
at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:39)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:131)
at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:84)
at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:113)
at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:54)
```

I've tried to add quarkus-bootstrap-maven-plugin with io.vavr:vavr as firstArtifact but it does'nt work.
I've also tried to add BuildStep with GeneratedClassBuildItem as a return value.
Could somebody help me?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @MagnusVåge, I found that this problem is related to generic classes. The simplest solution is to create some kind of wrapper or just cast.

I've created my own wrapper to vert'ex event bus that do this for me.
[AppEventBus.java](https://github.com/cssrumi/airq-common/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/airq/common/process/AppEventBus.java)